# Known mutual exclusion schemes in linux drivers

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently reading [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition chapter 5: Concurrency and Race Conditions](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf). The author claims that Read-Copy-Update scemes are sometimes used in writing drivers for linux. He then goes into depth about why they are used, but he gives very limited information about 'in-the-wild' code to look at. His two examples are networkrouting tables and the Starmode radio IP driver. Is there any other place where they show up?
(The book was published in 2009, so this scheme may have gotten more prevelent or has been replaced by now)
(Possibly better asked in the linux stackexchange forum?)

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the filesystems use rcu locks, because files are expected to be updated, while being read.

Refer to "3. WHAT ARE SOME EXAMPLE USES OF CORE RCU API?" from 
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt

Comment: That has roughly the same information as the book I referenced. It has examples of its use, I'm looking for real-life uses.

Comment: Then just take the Linux source and grep for occurrences of RCU API calls, it's not that hard.